# C++ OpenGL/SDL 2.0 faild to load a texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, loading, sdl-2

if i try to load a Texture i get this error:

```
Access violation reading location.
Unhandled exception at 0x651B5A17 (nvcuda.dll) in nsighttest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access  violation reading location 0x00000010.
```

image:
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/error1wlbsuf0iv.png

Debug image:
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/debugatc1xerob5.png

```
unsigned int loadTexture(const char*  filename, texProperties properties)
{
    GLint numberofcolors = 0;
    GLenum format;
    SDL_Surface * img = IMG_Load(filename);

    cout << "Image height: " << img->h << endl;
    cout << "Image width: " << img->w << endl;
    cout << "Images Pixels: " << img->pixels << endl;
    cout << "Images BitsPerPixel: " << img->format->BitsPerPixel << endl;
    cout << "Images Rmask: " << img->format->Rmask << endl;
    cout << "Images Surface: " << img << endl;


    if(!(&img)) { std::cout << "Fehler beim laden des bildes: " << filename; std::cout << std::endl; }
    if(img->format->BitsPerPixel == 4) {
        if(img->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff) { format = GL_RGBA; }
        else { format = GL_BGRA; }
        numberofcolors = 4;
    } else {
        if(img->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff) { format = GL_RGB; } 
        else { format = GL_BGR; }
        numberofcolors = 3;
    }

    unsigned int id;
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, properties.getMagFilter());
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, properties.getMinFilter());

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, properties.getTextureWrap());
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, properties.getTextureWrap());

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, properties.getAnisotropy());

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 , numberofcolors=4?GL_RGBA:GL_RGB, img->w, img->w, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->pixels);
    SDL_FreeSurface(img);
    return id;
}
```

The error comes from "glTexImage2D(...)".

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return value of `SDL_LoadBMP()`?  Or verifying that the `SDL_Surface` you're getting back is in fact `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5`?

Comment: i have check the return, but i got some number and i try it with "GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5" too but same result

Comment: I would hazard a guess that, as with 99% of image problems, it isn't loading as it's in the wrong location or something. You need to check that `SDL_Surface* img` is a valid memory location ie not NULL after you do `SDL_LoadBMP`

Comment: Use 24 bit BMP with three channels.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the glTexImage2D() function, it looks like you are using 
`img->w` twice, rather than using `img->h` for the second one.

Try calling

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 , numberofcolors=4?GL_RGBA:GL_RGB, img->w, /*Use height as second parameter, rather than width!*/img->h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->pixels);
```

Instead.